# Building an array by skipping blank values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and was surprised that there isn't a function to insert elements in an array (my previous question). So I rethought my approach a bit.

On screen I have the following example table 'allActualWeights'. There are a lot of blanks (no weight value) that I want to get rid of (the table is different everytime). So the end result should be 'actualWeights'.

In my code I tried the following:

```
Option Base 1
Dim allActualWeights
allActualWeights = Range("A6:E29").Value
Dim actualWeights
actualWeights = allActualWeights

For Index = 1 To 24
    If allActualWeights(Index, 2) <> 0 Then
        ReDim actualWeights(Index, 5)
        actualWeights(Index, 1) = allActualWeights(Index, 1)
        actualWeights(Index, 2) = allActualWeights(Index, 2)
        actualWeights(Index, 3) = allActualWeights(Index, 3)
        actualWeights(Index, 4) = allActualWeights(Index, 4)
        actualWeights(Index, 5) = allActualWeights(Index, 5)
    End If
Next Index

Range("G6:K29") = actualWeights
```

But I'm not getting the results I hoped for.
What am I doing wrong, or is there a better approach?

[image: screendump]

Comment: Okay. So... one loop to get a counter, then declare an array, and finally another loop to fill the new array?

Comment: Is it strictly necessary for the purpose of your code to use arrays, or you are open to different approaches too (e.g. filtering out blank values in column B, deleting rows where cell in column B is empty etc.)?

Comment: @ mlm0b11011: the allActualWeights is what the user sees... and also what gets filled by the user.  So yes, I would like to use arrays (also for the calculations I have... all based on arrays).

Comment: You can only ReDim the last dimension in a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Could you sort the data first to get all the blanks at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim allActualWeights, actualweights(), i As Long, n As Long, c As Long
    Dim rngSource As Range

    Set rngSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:E29")

    With rngSource
        allActualWeights = .Value
        'size the output array # of rows to count of values in ColB
        ReDim actualweights(1 To Application.CountA(.Columns(1)), _
                            1 To .Columns.Count)
    End With

    n = 1
    For i = LBound(allActualWeights, 1) To UBound(allActualWeights, 1)
        If Len(allActualWeights(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            For c = LBound(allActualWeights, 2) To UBound(allActualWeights, 2)
                actualweights(n, c) = allActualWeights(i, c)
            Next c
            n = n + 1  'next output row
        End If
    Next i

    'put the array on the sheet
    Range("G6").Resize(UBound(actualweights, 1), UBound(actualweights, 2)) = actualweights

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it and is easily maintainable...

```
Sub ActualWeights()

    Dim c&, i&, j&, n&, a, b

    With [a6:e29] '<-- allActualWeights 

        a = .Value2
        n = UBound(a) - Application.CountBlank(.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1))
        ReDim b(1 To n, 1 To UBound(a, 2))

        For i = 1 To UBound(a)
            If a(i, 2) Then
                c = c + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    b(c, j) = a(i, j)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        .Offset(, 6).Resize(n) = b

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tough one... I tried both... and selected Tim's because of his comments.